# Determine whether the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}-\sqrt{\ln\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)}$ converges or diverges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Estimate its value (between two integers) if the series is convergent. (Hint: Apply the Mean Value Theorem for integrals to $\ln\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)$ and then apply the squeeze theorem.)

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. By the way, take the opportunity to take the [Tour], if you haven't done it already. See also some tips on [ask], on [formatting help](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help) and on writing down equations using [LaTeX / MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020).


Can you please [edit] your post and write your attempts at solving the problem? If your question is clear and focused on your specific difficulty and you show your effort in solving the problem, it's more likely to get good and helping answers.

Comment: Please don't change the question after it has been answered.  That invalidates the answers that people were kind enough to give you.

Answer (score 2):

We have that

$$\ln\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)=\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\sim\frac1n-\frac1{2n^2}+O\left(\frac1{n^3}\right)$$

then

$$\sqrt{\ln\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\left(1-\frac1{2n}+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)\right)^\frac12=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\left(1-\frac1{4n}+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)\right)$$

and therefore

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}-\sqrt{\ln\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)}=\frac1{4n\sqrt n}+O\left(\frac1{n^2\sqrt n}\right)$$